# Removing duplicate equivalence classes from a list

Tags: python, list, distinct-values

I am looking for a way to take a list of elements, some of which may be "equivalent", and return a list with no equivalent elements.  My rough attempt is this:

```
unique = []
for item1 in mylist:
    include = 1
    for item2 in unique:
      if are_these_equivalent(item1, item2):
        include = 0
        break        #no need to examine anymore items
    if include == 1:
      unique.append(item1)
```

I would guess that algorithmically there's not much to be done, but it feels like the code is a little messy.  Are there any nice ways to spruce it up?

**EDIT:**
The equivalence I am using is whether two permutations are conjugate in S_n, but any abstraction of equivalent (in the sense of [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class)) should work the same.

Comment: What is meant by equivalent?

Comment: Please **clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Comment: You can substantially improve performance of your code by making `unique` a `set()` (change `unique.append` to `unique.add`), because sets have much better membership lookup time.

Comment: Even though there isn't much to be done algorithmically... I think there is a bug in your code. The last two lines should be one indentation to the left. Now you are assuming an item is unique if the first other one is not similar. And addng the same item multiple times.

Comment: And also comparing the item to itself, making it un-unique even when you fix the indentation.

Comment: Someone already asked this question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924421/is-there-a-standard-way-to-partition-an-interable-into-equivalence-classes-given

Comment: @DYZ About making unique a set, there's no lookup happening.  Will sets still be faster for iterating over and for appending?

Comment: Actually, you are right. There are no lookups in you code, and appending to a list is indeed faster than insertion (iteration is faster, too).

Comment: You should consider using a [union-find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Simply union all of the equivalent items and then take the value at the root node of each tree in the forest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the light of what was said in the comments, here is an improved and corrected version of the code. It is only tangentially better than your original code.

```
unique = []
for item1 in mylist:
  for item2 in unique:
    if are_these_equivalent(item1, item2):
      break
  else:
    unique.append(item1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a set to remove any duplicates easily.

```
unique = list(set(unique))
```

`set(unique)` would create a set, which, by definition, cannot contain any repeats. Calling `list()` on that would turn the returned set back into a list. This is not necessary, and depends on what you plan to do with it after.

Comment: `set()` uses a very specific definition of equivalence to remove duplicates that in general may not work for the OP.

Comment: @DYZ that's true! We'll see what OP says, and I'll modify accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like you may be looking for a "Set"?

Something like this perhaps?

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,5,6,
           'apples', 'apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'oranges']

unique = [i for i in set(my_list)]
print unique
```

Pretty much, when you use `set()`, you can pass it an iterable (a list)
and it will only contain values once. If they come up again in the list, they are ignored.